# AJAX don't submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
var just = $("#just").val();
var id = $("#id").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "cod_ajax/just.php",
    data: "id="+id+"&just="+just,
    cache: false,
    success:function(e){
      alert("Success");
    } 
});
```

And I have this in ***cod_ajax/just.php***

```
require "../../db.php";

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $update = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE table SET just1 = '1', just2 = '".$_POST['just']."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'") or  die(mysqli_error());

    if ($update) {
        echo "Success!";
    } else {
        echo "Error :(";
    }
}
```

The SQL code is all acording to database, the db require is okay too, but something seems to not work. I tried to erase one of the data provived by AJAX, like the id but it didn't work anyway nor the just2.

Also checked if both variables where empty or not unexistent but both have information in them.

***MORE INFORMATION***

I ran this on local server, no errors on console, **alert(e) gave me success**, all Jquery is included in page.

Comment: try to alert response from PHP, so `alert(e)`

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Your code looks fine, check the network tab in your browser to confirm if the Ajax quest is being sent. You can see the response and see the return status code

Comment: @JayBlanchard Check my edit in MORE INFORMATION

Comment: change the name of your table(add a character or something), that's going to throw an error so you can check whats the query.

Comment: @RildoGomez table already has a name, I just hide it with that name

Comment: i know i mean change this line of your code
$update=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE table1 SET just1 = '1', just2 = '".$_POST['just']."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'") or die(mysqli_error());
insted of table (or whatever the name is) to table1 so when you send that to the db its going to throw an error because that table doesnt exist in your db but you can check what query you sent at least (check the console)

Comment: Try using `data: {id: id, just: just}` instead of constructing the string with concatenation.

Comment: `cache: false` is unnecessary for `POST`, they're never cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to reserve posted values first, then use them in update statement like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['just'])) {
    $id_val = $_POST['id'];
    $just_val = $_POST['just'];
    $update = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE table SET just1 = '1', just2 = '$just_val' WHERE id = 'id_val'") or die(mysqli_error());
    if ($update) {
        echo "Success!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error :(";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store first variables from post then use in query.
So

```
$id =  $_POST["id"];
```

Same for others. 
Also you might find useful to send data at least as url encoded.

And then put in query.